# Auto Row Number in SSRS Table with Grouped Rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working with SSRS 2008. In one of my report  I have a table with 3 columns. Sr. No, Column 1, Column2. Sr. No is -RowNumber("DataSet") and other are two are data set columns. I have grouped (Row Group) my table on Column 1 and Column 2. This is ok but the Sr.No column doesn't show right count it shows row number of grouped row e.g 2,4,9,10 so on. I want to keep the Sr.No or row number after grouping and on top of my table I want to show the count of rows in my table after grouping.

please suggest

Comment: Would you be able to give an example table of your desired output based on some sample data? I found it a bit difficult to tell what is required here just from your description.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For distinct numbering of rows you can try this:

```
=RunningValue(CountDistinct("YourTableName"),Count,"YourTableName")
```

If you have only one grouping level in your report, you could group your values in the SQL query and then add new column `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` numbering your rows in SQL query already.

Comment: How can i count grouped records in table?

Comment: If you group your values by only one column, you can add the expression (outside your group): =CountDistinct(<yourGroupingColumnName>). You can also add count of rows in page header, but then you have to display your whole table on one page.

Comment: I am grouping my table on 2 columns and I want to show the count of grouped rows (total rows after grouping) outside the table.Will it work?

Comment: What if you try this (in cell outside your group): =CountDistinct(Fields!yourGroupingColumnName1.Value + Fields!yourGroupingColumnName.Value2)

Comment: But I am looking for something outside the table.